# 火の車 Where did it come from

Tags: translation, etymology, religion

My sensei in class told us about 火の車 that means someone in a difficult financial strait . I was wondering what does it have to do with fire 火 and a car 車?

Comment: To understand what 火車　means I recommend you to read "All she was worth" (/"火車") from Miyuki Miyabe. The whole story develops from the idea of 火車. In chapter 10 Buddhist mythology is explicitly discussed in form of a dialogue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As written on [gogen allguide](http://gogen-allguide.com/hi/hinokuruma.html):

Apparently it's from the Buddhist 火車{かしゃ} piece of mythology. The story goes that those who were rotten in their lifetimes would be carried into the flames of hell on a cart driven by a petty demon. This suffering was then later metaphorically applied to financial difficulties.

A possible alternate explanation is that it's connected to another Buddhist idea, 火宅{かたく}, which compares the pains of the world with a house on fire. Supposedly this may have been applied to 車 to represent financial difficulties specifically.